# What does "Stone walls do not make a prison" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

What does the following idiom mean

> Stone walls do not make a prison.

Can anyone tell me situations where the given idiom can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct quotation is

> Stone walls do not a prison make.

It is from the seventeenth-century poem [To Althea from prison](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44657/to-althea-from-prison). Richard Lovelace was imprisoned on a political charge not long before the English Civil War. The poem is full of images of freedom and captivity. His theme is that his mind is free (to support the King) even though his body is in prison.